# unable to bind data to listbox in windows phone using mvvm architecture

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-7.1

Am trying to bind the data collection from json object from async callback response to the listbox in windows phone through implementing mvvm pattern...I am able to get the data collection to the observablecollectionm<> object but then unable to bind it to UI listbox control in .xaml page.

the following is the code in app.xaml

```
 public static countryListViewModel countrylistVM { get; set; }
```

Below is code in countries.xaml page.

```
public Countries()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (App.countrylistVM == null)
        App.countrylistVM = new countryListViewModel();

    DataContext = App.countrylistVM;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (!App.countrylistVM.IsDataLoaded)
    {
        App.countrylistVM.Loadcountries();
        App.countrylistVM.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

the below is code for model.

```
public class Model: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Countriesdata countries;

    public Countriesdata Countries
    {
        get { return countries; }
        set
        {
            if (countries != value)
            {
                countries = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Countries");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Countriesdata : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string countryid;

    public string Countryid
    {
        get { return countryid; }
        set
        {
            if (countryid != value)
            {
                countryid = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Countryid");
            }
        }
    }

    private string countryname;

    public string Countryname
    {
        get { return countryname; }
        set
        {
           if (countryname != value)
           {
               countryname = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("Countryname");
           }
        }
    }
```

the following is the code for viewmodel

```
public class countryListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    HttpWebRequest crequest;
    HttpWebResponse cresponse;

    private bool isDataLoaded = false;

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get { return isDataLoaded; }

        set
        {
            if (isDataLoaded != value)
            {
                isDataLoaded = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsDataLoaded");
            }
        }
    }

    private Countriesdata countries;

    public Countriesdata Countries
    {
        get { return countries; }
        set
        {
            if (countries != value)
            {
                countries = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Countries");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Countriesdata> countrylist;

    public ObservableCollection<Countriesdata> Countrylist
    {
        get { return countrylist; }
        set
        {
            if (countrylist != value)
            {
                countrylist = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Countrylist");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }

    public void Loadcountries()
    {
        try
        {
            crequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceurls.getcountries);
            crequest.Accept = "application/json";
            IAsyncResult cresult = (IAsyncResult)crequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Responsecallbackcountries), crequest);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    private void Responsecallbackcountries(IAsyncResult cresult)
    {
        try
        {
            string countryresult = string.Empty;
            cresponse = (HttpWebResponse)crequest.EndGetResponse(cresult);
            using (var Stream = cresponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var Reader = new StreamReader(Stream))
                {
                    countryresult = Reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                JObject Country = JObject.Parse(countryresult);
                JArray Root = (JArray)Country["Countries"];

                if (Root.Count != 0)
                {
                    countrylist = new ObservableCollection<Countriesdata>();
                    var Dictionary = Root.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
                    JToken Tctry;

                    foreach (var cntry in Dictionary)
                    {
                        Tctry = cntry.Value;
                        countrylist.Add(
                            new Countriesdata
                            {
                                Countryid = Convert.ToString(Tctry["ID"]),
                                Countryname = Convert.ToString(Tctry["Name"])

                            });
                    }
                    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        Views.Countries vc = new Views.Countries();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

the below is the code for .xaml page.

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lstcountries" 
                 Margin="0,0,-12,0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Countrylist}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Selectedcity, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 SelectionChanged="lstcountries_SelectionChanged" Background="white">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Countriesdata.Countryid}" Foreground="Black" 
                            Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Countriesdata.Countryname}" Foreground="Black"
                           />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Does your ObservableCollection get populated, with the data, and only the binding doesn't work?

Comment: In your App.xaml where do you create the countrylistVM? because the code what you shared only shows that it is a property but nothing creates an instance of it.

Comment: my observablecollection object gets populated successfully but binding the same to UI does not work.

Comment: I have created instance of countrylistVM in xaml.cs file..in the initializecomponent() method of countries.xaml...if you could see...dont know why it is not working

Comment: Can you please go through my code above once and help me resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

Your data template refers to the model, rather than the items in the collection the listbox is being bound to.

Instead, try:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Countryid}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Countryname}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I have tried the above...but It didn't work...could you please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: You do realise you're setting both the foreground and background to be black?